# List of voted pins per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used the acts as votable gem to like pins. Now I want a view (my favorites) with all the pins a user has liked. I get stuck in making this happen.

If have this in my pins controller file:

```
def my_favorites
  @pins = current_user.pins
end

def like
  @pin.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end

def unlike
  @pin.unliked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end
```

And this in my favorites view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>  
    <h1>Mijn favoriete recepten</h1>
    <p>Bekijk hier jouw <b> nummer </b> favoriete recepten die jij lekker vindt.</p> 
          <div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
            <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
                  <div class="box panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <b>Recept: </b>
                        <p><%= link_to pin.description, pin_path(pin) %></p>
                        <b>Toegevoegd door: </b>
                        <p><%= link_to image_tag(pin.user.image_file_name), pin %></p>
                        <div class="actions">
                           <%= link_to like_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
                              Vind ik lekker!!!!
                              <% end %>
                              <%= link_to unlike_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                              Niet mijn smaak
                              <% end %>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'pages/login' %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: What do you mean with get stuck? Do you receive an error message? Could you elaborate more on what the problem is?

Comment: According to the documentation of the gem https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable I have to include somewhere something like @user.find_liked_items to make sure only the liked items are shown. Do I need to add this to the controller or the view? I tried both options but in any case I get errors. What would be the correct syntax to implement this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the pins controller in the following and now it is working:

```
def my_favorites
@pins = current_user.find_liked_items
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>  
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>  
        <% if current_user.voted_for? pin %>
```

That should be at the top of the file